# Android grid view select image on scroll automatically select image

Tags: android, image, gridview

I am creating a gridView and in that i am showing images the requirement is that if user click the image then the border of image should appear and that is happening but the problem is that when i click the image and scroll down some other images are automatically selected and when i refresh the list of images in grid view the selected image become un selected.

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        View view = convertView;

        final int Position = position;

        if (view == null) {
            view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_grid_image,
                    parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            assert view != null;
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
            holder.imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

            holder.imageView
                    .setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                            formulas.getWidth(200), formulas.getWidth(200)));

            holder.progressBar = (ProgressBar) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.progress);
            holder.progressBar
                    .setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                            formulas.getWidth(200), formulas.getWidth(200)));

            view.setTag(R.id.image, holder.imageView);

            view.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }



        holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                // Log.e("", "image :"
                // + images.get(position).getThumbNailUrl());

                // ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v;
                // int getPosition = (Integer) imageView.getTag();

                if (thumbnailsselection.get(Position)) {
                    holder.imageView
                            .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.borderonclick);
                    thumbnailsselection.set(Position, false);

                } else {
                    holder.imageView
                            .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border);
                    thumbnailsselection.set(Position, true);
                }

            }
        });

        imageLoader.displayImage(images.get(position).getThumbNailUrl(),
                holder.imageView, options,
                new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                        holder.progressBar.setProgress(0);
                        holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view,
                            FailReason failReason) {
                        holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri,
                            View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                        holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }, new ImageLoadingProgressListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgressUpdate(String imageUri,
                            View view, int current, int total) {
                        holder.progressBar.setProgress(Math.round(100.0f
                                * current / total));
                    }
                });
        // holder.checkbox.setChecked(thumbnailsselection.get(position));

        return view;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        ProgressBar progressBar;

    }

}
```

the thumbnailSelection is the boolean arraylist to know which image is selected.
the grid view in which i am setting the adapter is.

```
showingImages = new GridView(this);

    // showingImages.setColumnWidth(90);
    // showingImages.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#EAEAEA"));
    showingImages.setHorizontalSpacing(2);
    showingImages.setVerticalSpacing(2);
    showingImages.setNumColumns(4);
    showingImages.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    // showingImages.setStretchMode(90);
    showingImages.setOnScrollListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's better to use an onClick on the GridView instead of the ImageView. Then you can call a public function of your adapter inside the gridview.onClick (adapter.itemSelected(int index). Then you can do what you want, you can keep one index in your adapter too (int selectedIndex) and reset this with a refresh to -1. In your getView-function, you can check if the position == selectedIndex and set a border if needed.
I think that an ImageButton can work too (not sure).

Answer (score 0):

**when i click the image and scroll down some other images are automatically selected**"

---

Your `convertView` in `GridView` will be reused, if previous item is clicked, its background is set, then when it is reused, the background remains dirty. So try set the background to normal in your `getView()` code

Answer (score 0):

Yet, I have not check your code. But you can use `onitemlongclicklistener` for performing your task.
In other way.

Do not use clickable objects in the grid. That case Android can not handle the click event of grid.
Instead use something to show similar user interface view. Than handle that objects click actions.

**false; put button in the grid to perform some click actions.**

**true; put an imageview instead of imagebutton and handle imageview's click events.**

Actually, you just need to make sure that the items in the grid aren't clickable. GridViews can't handle clickable items. Buttons for example won't work. And also if you made an item from a LinearLayout, or any other non-clickable item, you have to make sure that you didn't set the property: clicable="true".